# Windows DFS File System Clustering

Tags: windows, dfs, windows-cluster

We're attempted to set up a high availability network for our file servers, and we're wanting to do a DFS file system cluster using the same back-end storage (our back-end storage has its own clustering mechanisms that it manages itself).

The question being, A. how would one go about setting up DFS clustering, and B. how can we get Windows to cooperate with multiple servers accessing the same SAN volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at this recently, but it was the case that in a Domain, the root NS couldn't be a cluster. It can have multiple tagets, and thus redundancy, but they can't be clustered on a shared volume. Folders under that NS can however be pointed to a cluster running DFS-N, with a shared volume.

So to answer your questions:
A. Install Cluster Services, create a new cluster on one box, join the other(s) to that cluster. Install DFS as usual after the clustered file shares are setup.
B. This is normally configured on the NAS device(s). Most have an option very similar to "allow concurrent connections" to a target.